# Angular Ui router - parameters disappearing from URL when anything on page causes a digest

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have a strange problem with UI-router. I have stripped all code relating to ui-router from my page, all that remains is my config code...

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $uiViewScrollProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, appConfig) {

        'use strict';

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/search");

        $stateProvider
            .state('search', {
                url: "/search?locationtext?&method?&page?",
                templateUrl: "templates/searchResults.tpl.html",
                controller: 'SearchResultsCtrl as searchResults',
                reloadOnSearch : false
            })


    });
```

So, basically when you go to the url domain.com/page it automatically changes the URL to domain.com/page#/search which is exactly what I want it to do.

Unfortunately when I click on anything on the page which triggers a digest cycle (e.g. open a modal, click a menu item) everything after the # disappears from the URL, which is bizarre.

No other code in my app does anything to the router. Any code on the page which runs when you click something is doing something entirely unrelated to routing.
Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: do you have a bunch of `<a href="#">` in use?

Comment: Your `url` parameter looks wrong (too many question marks). Shouldn't it be `/search?locationtext&method&page`?

Comment: Charlietfl, I do often do that but I'm not in the office now so can't check. If that is what's causing the problem then I could fix it easily tomorrow. That would be really dumb of me.

Comment: Phil. As I understood it, optional parameters each need a ? after them because some might be optional and others not. I may be wrong though.

Comment: No, the "?" just indicates beginning of optional parameters

Comment: `?` is used to separate url path with queries (or called parameters), `&` is used to separate each query items. Every query item is optional in HTML, no way to make them compulsory in url.

Comment: charlietfl, that was the correct answer, I was being a dumbass. I guess I should really not be using an A tag because I'm not sure what to put in the href and if I omit the href it doesn't style in some browsers. I can't use the button tag unfortunately because that is styled in a particular way in our app which I'd have to write. Thinking of using a custom <trigger> tag instead seeing as this is an angular app with loads of custom elements anyway. Thanks again, if you add it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: To the others, I need to understand how parameters work in the router. I understand what the ? does in a normal url, but when everything is after the hash anyway, what is the difference between optional parameters, search parameters etc. What does the ? actually do when you're not in html5mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As charlietfl pointed out in the comments, I was using  with an ng-click on it but the hash was still overwriting the URL whenever I clicked on anything. I hate web development.